# Random black screen after suspend on Ubuntu 14.04/16.04

Tags: 16.04

I randomly get a black screen after waking my PC from suspend. Where do I need to look to find what the issue is?

Graphics card: NVIDIA GTX 980 (driver version - 375.20)

Motherboard: ASUS Z170 (latest BIOS)

Comment: So sometimes the display comes back, and sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: Yes. I may get like 4-5 successful resumes from suspend, and then the next time I will get a black screen.

Comment: When you only get the black screen, see if you can get to `tty1` by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1. (Try it first while the computer is still on so that you know you got the key combo right. To return to the GUI: CTRL+ALT+F7)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've just put my PC to suspend, and got a black screen on wake up. I couldn't get to tty1 with CTRL+ALT+F1 (I've tried the combo before suspending).